# Xamarin Android: Loop all controls in an Activity

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, imageview

I have an Android app, where an action will be performed whenever a user clicks on an image(of which there are several).
I would like to set up a listener collectively for each of these images, let's say we have 6.
Rather than saying

```
myImg0.Click += new MyImgClick;
myImg1.Click += new MyImgClick;
```

I was hoping for a way to run a foreach loop to set the click event listeners quickly,
something like

```
foreach(img i in Application)
{
   i.Click += new MyImgClick;
}
```

Then I could use the event handler, using the 'sender' parameter would allow me to access the individual image that was clicked.

I have tried reading up on the Activity and Bundle classes but haven't found anything worthwhile thus far.
This doesn't seem to be a common approach, as most searches have just returned a solution for "setting event listeners".

Answer (score 1):

You can traverse your View Hierarchy and get all the ImageViews you want with a simple recursive method like this:

```
private IEnumerable<T> GetViewsByType<T>(ViewGroup root) where T : View
{
    var children = root.ChildCount;
    var views = new List<T>();
    for (var i = 0; i < children; i++)
    {
        var child = root.GetChildAt(i);
        if (child is T myChild)
            views.Add(myChild);
        else if (child is ViewGroup viewGroup)
            views.AddRange(GetViewsByType<T>(viewGroup));
    }
    return views;
}
```

Any `ViewGroup` type of `View` will work as input here, so `LinearLayout`, `RelativeLayout` etc.

If you don't give your root layout and ID you can always get the root with:

```
var root = Window.DecorView.FindViewById<ViewGroup>(Android.Resource.Id.Content);
```

Then you can run the method on this root with and get all `ImageView`s with:

```
var imageViews = GetViewsByType<ImageView>(root);
```

I've tested this on this layout and it found all the `ImageView`s just fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
      <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
      <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <ImageView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
      </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  </RelativeLayout>
  <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ImageView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Whether it is the optimal way of doing it, I highly doubt it. Maybe you should think a little bit about using a `RecyclerView`, `GridView` or some other view that uses and `Adapter` to be more memory efficient. It may be a better solution for you.